# Docker Compose is not working due to proxy issue windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Docker compose is not working when ran from windows command line. Seems like a proxy issue but i am really not sure what is the work around for the proxy settings for windows? I am not even sure if this is even related to a proxy issue? I am new to the docker technology any help will be appreciated please!

```
C:\Users\user\myproject>docker-compose up
WARNING: The PWD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Building jbpm-workbench
Step 1/6 : FROM jboss/jbpm-workbench:latest
ERROR: Service 'jbpm-workbench' failed to build: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```